# Who is talking to Claudia in the end shot?

Tags: ending, magnolia

In PT Anderson's Magnolia, we learn that Claudia is most likely the victim of sex abuse.  She is filled with self-loathing throughout the movie.

In the end scene, we see her as we did towards the beginning - in bed - but now all in white, and smiling at last.  A man is standing in frame.  It's not possible to see his head.  Hearing him say the name 'Claudia' is barely audible.

I don't think is her father.  The character standing looked too lean (and is moving too deftly).  The same is true for Reilly's cop character.

Can anyone say definitively who she is talking to in the end scene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [shooting screenplay](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/magnolia.html), it is [Officer Jim Kurring](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0058256/):

```
INT. CLAUDIA'S APARTMENT - THAT MOMENT

     CAMERA holds on Claudia.  She's sitting up in bed, covers around 
     her, staring into space....a SONG plays....for a very, very long
     time she doesn't move until she looks up and sees someone 
     enter her bedroom....a FIGURE from the back enters FRAME and walks
     in and sits on the edge of the bed....from the back it is clear 
     that it's Jim Kurring. She tears a bit and looks at him...HOLD....

     She turns her eyes from him and looks INTO THE CAMERA and smiles.

                                                          CUT TO BLACK.


                                END.
```

Also, if you listen carefully to the voice of the person speaking to her who presumably is the person which sits on the bed, it is the voice of John C. Reilly.

Comment: ok.  I couldnt hear any of the dialogue when I watched recently.  Excellent.  Backed up thricefold.  To you sir, go the spoils.